# Numbered headers in jupyter notebooks

Tags: markdown, jupyter

I'd like to change the way Jupyter displays the so called *heading cells*. By default, heading levels are only differentiated through a different font size. 
I'd like jupyter to display hierarchical numbered titles so that :

```
# Heading 1

# Heading 2

## Sub Heading

# Heading 3
```

would display something like :

**1 Heading 1

    2 Heading 2

    2.1 Sub Heading

    3 Heading 3**

I don't get this with Jupyter 4.2.3.

Answer (score 19):

If it's only about getting the headings and numbering, then use markdown syntax, you wouldn't need any extensions (as suggested in Xiaodong's answer).

If you're trying to not only number your headings, but also looking for something that actually organizes and help you navigate around the notebook in addition to just numbering, then you will need ToC2 extension.

1. Install [nbextensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions) and it's [control panel](https://github.com/Jupyter-contrib/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator)

   ```
   conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
   ```
2. Enable [ToC2](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/toc2)

[image]

3. Refresh and you now have nicely organized notebook

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But Leo have the requested behavior without any extension. They must be something simpler.

Comment: I agree with @johann, the query is asking a simple question and this solution is extremely heavyweight and lacks specificity to the question.

Comment: -1 for "I don't think you're trying to just number your headings." Please don't change the scope. People may indeed just want to number the headings.

Comment: Thanks for the comment; I've updated my answer. I agree that this is not the answer to the question, however, this may be useful for those who come here looking for more.

Comment: This is very helpful! Also works on JupyterLab with <toc> extension:
https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-toc

Comment: is there an equivalent for vscode?

Comment: Not sure, but this worked for me I was trying to get rid of those pesky numbers in my headings. Just had to disable Toc2.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution to this problem in Jupyter Lab (mine is 3.3.4) without any extension. If you have Anaconda, then both classic Jupyter and Jupyter lab comes preinstalled.

Go to Settings -> Advanced Settings Editor. In the left pane, select `table of contents` and enable the h1 numbering as follows.

[image]

Now open any Jupyter-notebook (.ipynb) and select The third icon on the very left panel [image]. This will bring down the table of contents. Now click on the icon with numbering above the table of contents [image].

Now you will see that all the headings and subheadings are numbered everywhere.

[image]

You can use the table of contents to navigate in the Jupyter notebook.

Comment: By "All your classical Jupyter Notebook will work in Jupyter Lab as well", do you mean. All your `.ipynb` Jupyter notebook files will work in JupyterLab as well"?

Comment: @Wayne yeah actually both are same.

Answer (score 2):

There is on tiny step I may overlooked:

```
conda> jupyter contrib nbextension install --user      # to activate js
```

perfectly explained in:
http://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

What you like is actually the default display style of jupyter notebook.

**Input cell with markdown:**
[image: Input cell with markdown]

**notebook display:**
[image: notebook display]

tested on notebook version 5.4.0

Comment: Thank you. It seems however it is not the default display style on jupyter 4.2.3. The question still holds : how do you modify the display style of jupyter so that it number the titles?

Comment: I have tried on notebook=4.2.3 as well, and got same numbered titles, so I could not re-create your problem.

Comment: I am using `5.5.0` and still not getting that :/ The numbering isn't happening by default (atleast for me)

Comment: I'm using 5.7 and not getting heading numbers.