# Numbered headings and table of contents in Google Colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, google-colaboratory, tableofcontents, heading

Is there a way to enable numbered headings and table of contents in Google Colab?

Similar question: [markdown - Numbered headers in jupyter notebooks - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189154/numbered-headers-in-jupyter-notebooks) for Jupyter Notebook (which requires an nbextension).

Need solution for Google Colab.

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer for a workaround by writing the numbers manually. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69541262/8691571

Use `# 1.&nbsp;Heading`

Answer (score -1):

Its very simple Here are the steps :

1. Create a new section.
2. add "#" before the heading you want to write
3. the heading appears in the "Table Of contents"

link : https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/markdown_guide.ipynb
this link shd solve your doubt.

Comment: The headings are not numbered.

Comment: Yes, it's not numbered.

Comment: This does not address OPs question.