# Google Colab headers don't show prepended number in Table of Contents

Tags: google-colaboratory

In Google Colaboratory, I like to create markdown section headers with a prepended number, like so:

```
# 1. My Notebook

-----

## 1. My section
```

However, when I look at the Table of Contents pane, the number does not show up.

[image]

When I instead use a letter, such as "A", the letter does show up.

[image]

How do I fix it so that the prepended numerals (e.g. `1.`) show up in the Table of Contents?

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like this:

```
# 1.&nbsp;Heading
## 1.1&nbsp;Sub-Heading
```

Using `&nbsp;` to replace the space.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
#@title strategy
```